# Sbt Custom Configuration with inherited tasks

Tags: sbt

If I define an SBT custom configuration in my Build.scala file as such:

`val custom = config("sam")`

and then I invoke a built in task (is that the right term?), as such

`sbt sam:test`

does the custom config propagate to the other inherited tasks. Eg, does `sbt sam:test` mean

`sbt sam:compile sam:test`

or

`sbt compile sam:test`

or neither ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [SBT Config extend vs DefaultSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162874/), you have to include the configuration explicitly into a project to be used. Using sbt 0.13's multi-project syntax, it looks like this:

```scala
val SamConfig = config("sam")

val root = (project in file(".")).
  configs(SamConfig).
  settings(
    // other settings here.
  )
```

> and then I invoke a built in task (is that the right term?), as such
>
> ```
> sbt sam:test
> ```
>
> does the custom config propagate to the other inherited tasks.

`test`, which delegates to `test:test`, is a built-in task; however, `sam:test` denotes `test` task scoped into `SamConfig`, which is undefined.

```
root> sam:test
[error] No such setting/task
[error] sam:test
[error]         ^
```

So no propagation there.

Comment: Ok I see, how would I get sam:test to invoke sam:compile ?