# SBT Config extend vs DefaultSettings

Tags: sbt

If I define an SBT config with

`val MyConfig = config("my") extend Test`

is that basically the same as doing

`val MyConfig = config("my")`
`val mySettings = inConfig(MyConfig)(Defaults.testSettings)`

and then importing mySettings inside a build definition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, calling `extend` method is not the same thing as calling `inConfig`. `extend` just returns a new configuration with passed in configurations prepended `extendsConfigs`, and it will not introduce any new settings.

When you add `MyConfig` into the project, it becomes part of the scoped key resolution path:

```scala
val MyConfig = config("my") extend Test

val root = (project in file(".")).
  configs(MyConfig)
```

Suppose you type `my:test` in the sbt shell. Since `test` task is not found under `my` configuration, it will traverse `extendsConfigs` and check if the tasks are available under them. The first one it's going to hit is `Test` since we *prepended* it. You can check this by running `inspect my:test`:

```
root> inspect my:test
[info] Task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Executes all tests.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/eugene/work/quick-test/sbt-so/}root/test:test
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:365
[info] Delegates:
[info]  my:test
[info]  test:test
[info]  runtime:test
[info]  compile:test
[info]  *:test
[info]  {.}/my:test
[info]  {.}/test:test
[info]  {.}/runtime:test
[info]  {.}/compile:test
[info]  {.}/*:test
[info]  */my:test
[info]  */test:test
[info]  */runtime:test
[info]  */compile:test
[info]  */*:test
[info] Related:
[info]  test:test
```

"Provided by" says it delegated to `root/test:test`. This mechanism allows you to share some of the settings but override others, but you still have to know the inner wiring of the settings scoped to tasks etc, so it's tricky business. You probably already know, but I'll link to [Additional test configurations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#additional-test-configurations), which specifically discusses configurations for testing.

Comment: So extends is a way of delegating keys if they are not set basically?

Comment: That and it shares `libraryDependencies` too, I think.

Comment: So what's the difference between MyConfig extending Test, MyConfig (extends nothing) and MyConifg <<= Copy All Test Config. Sounds like in practice nothing?

Comment: In theory yes, but in practice it could be difficult to fake the entire settings graph like source and library dependencies.

Comment: So if I want to use myconfig:test with all the normal settings from test, except with a couple of changes, is the former or latter the better way ?

Comment: `extend` I think is the way to go. Mostly-normal-test is the scenario described in [Additional test configurations with shared sources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#additional-test-configurations-with-shared-sources).