# Delegation of custom configurations using 'extend' in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm writing a plugin for sbt which has two configurations - `base` and `ext`.
I'd like for `ext` to extend `base`, so I declared the following:

```
name := "blah"
lazy val base = config("base")
lazy val ext = config("ext") extend base
name in base := "something"
```

When inspecting `ext:name`, it is equal to "blah" and does not delegate to `base:name`, as I intended.

In [SBT Config extend vs DefaultSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162874/sbt-config-extend-vs-defaultsettings) I saw that the extending config needs to be declared in the project (I assume that delegation isn't a property of a config, rather how configs relate inside a project?).

My question is, since I'm writing a plugin, I can't assume anything about how the users' projects are defined. How can I go about declaring delegation between my configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just found this out myself: The configurations need to be automatically added to the project when the plugin is loaded.

Just like there's `projectSettings` that can be overridden to add settings with an autoplugin, there's `projectConfigurations` that can automatically add configs!

`override val projectConfigurations = Seq(base, ext)`